# Add another blank store/pst under Personal Folders in Outlook

Tags: outlook, mapi

I want to add an empty pst file/ data store to my Outlook. Reason is I want it to be seperate from the user's Personal Folder store/pst.

is this possible? I dont want the inbox, sent items etc. folders to be shown. Do i need a custom store provider or is there another way? If I need a store provider, is there a good free or commercial one available?

Answer (score 1):

You can add as many PST files as you like.  Either from the very bottom of Outlook folders (in the generic view) or through Control Panel Mail icon (although not sure about this on windows 7).  Choose your account as needed, and then choose add/modify message stores.

However, each one of them will have the default set of folders.  With some work you may be able to get rid of them, but they are in a separate folder tree, that's easy enough to hide or remove and re-add later on, if you like.